# Why the 0-order coefficient of Legendre equation should be nonnegative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

When we try to find the solutions of Legendre equation
$$ (1-x^2)y''-2xy'+\lambda y=0 , \quad y|_{x=\pm 1}<+\infty$$
we may let the 0-order coefficient $\lambda\geq 0$, this conclusion could be verified by the Legendre function is bounded at the point $\pm 1$. But if we have not solve the equation, how can I gain this conclusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legendre equation can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[(1-x^2)y'\right]+\lambda y=0. \tag{1}
$$
Multiplying both sides of $(1)$ by $y$, and integrating from $-1$ to $1$, we obtain
\begin{align}
\lambda\int_{-1}^1y^2\,dx&=-\int_{-1}^1y\frac{d}{dx}\left[(1-x^2)y'\right]dx \\
&=\left.-y(1-x^2)y'\right|_{-1}^1+\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)(y')^2\,dx. \tag{2}
\end{align}
If $y$ and $y'$ are bounded at $x=\pm 1$, the first term on the RHS of $(2)$ vanishes, hence
$$
\lambda\int_{-1}^1y^2\,dx=\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)(y')^2\,dx\geq 0. \tag{3}
$$
If $y$ is a nontrivial solution to $(1)$, then $\int_{-1}^1y^2\,dx>0$; therefore, it follows from $(3)$ that $\lambda\geq 0$.